# insert a span from jQuery after dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a span after dynamically generated table, but the span is getting added before the contents of table are getting loaded.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    dash();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#th").append("<span>span</span>");
    });
});

function dash()
{ 
     $("#hu").html();
     $("#hu").append("<tr> <td> see this </td> </tr>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Insert content after each p element</button>
<div align="right" id="th">
<table id="hu" align="right">
<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The span is getting added before hello. I want the span to be displayed after the table contents.

Comment: if you this link i appears `after hello`

Comment: what is the purpose of `$("#hu").html();` in function dash()

Comment: Dont allow table to use align="right"

Comment: That's because you are using the `align` attribute. The element is _appended_ , i.e. "The span is getting added"  after "hello. "

Comment: @Vohuman i want the table to be aligned to right and also the span should be to right... that why i have used align attibute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span is being added at the bottom in the dom. You are seeing it before the table because the table is aligned right.Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    dash();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#th").append("<span>span</span><br/>");
    });
});

function dash()
{ 
     $("#hu").html();
     $("#hu").append("<tr> <td> see this </td> </tr>");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button>Insert content after each p element</button>
<div align="right" id="th">
<table id="hu" >
<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
  <br/>
</div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you write something like this `$("#hu").after("<span>span</span>");`

this will put span after table

Comment: Indeed, but that won't fix the issue he is having. What you suggest is just another way of doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `after` function like the way @Reoxey did. However, please ensure you're adding your script before the `</body>` tag instead of using it on the `<head>` tag. Adding Javascript before the `</body>` tag is recommended to prevents render blocking while the scripts load and is much better for site perception head. Adding Javascript before the `</body>` tag will also improve the site loading speed.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Manu try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    dash();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#hu").append("<span>span</span>");
    });
});

function dash()
{ 
     $("#hu").html();
     $("#hu").append("<tr> <td> see this </td> </tr>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Insert content after each p element</button>
<div align="right" id="th">
<table id="hu" align="right">
<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should use table id i.e `#hu` to append as place of `#th`

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
$("#th").append("<span>span</span>");
```

to:

```
$("table").append("<span>span</span>");
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tk4h80yn/

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    dash();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#hu").after("<span>span</span>");
    });
  });
```